# Finding basis of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

1. Find a basis of vector space:

$V=\{(x-y,3y,2y-x,2x):x,y\in \mathbb{R}\}$

2. Find a basis of vector space in which all of the vector $(1,3,0,4)$ coordinates are $4$.

I tried to solve the first part of this task ($B$ is found basis):

$(x-y,3y,2y-x,2x) \Rightarrow x(1,0,-1,2)+y(-1,3,2,0)\Rightarrow B=((1,0,-1,2),(-1,3,2,0))$

I don`t know how I can solve the second part of this task.

Comment: I don't get what you are asking for the second part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since\begin{align}(1,3,0,4)&=2(1,0,-1,2)+(-1, 3, 2, 0)\\&=4\left(\frac12,0,\frac{-1}2,1\right)+4\left(\frac{-1}4,\frac34,\frac12,0\right).\end{align}So, the basis that your after is$$\left\{\left(\frac12,0,\frac{-1}2,1\right),\left(\frac{-1}4,\frac34,\frac12,0\right)\right\}.$$

Comment: That's not a basis of $V$.  The second task is to find another basis of $V$, necessarily having two elements, $C = \{c_1, c_2\}$, such that the coordinates of the vector $(1,3,0,4)$ (given in the same underlying basis as used to give the elements of $V$) are $(4,4)$ when expressed in the $C$ basis.

Comment: @EricTowers I was after a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $(1,3,0,4)=2\cdot(1,0,-1,2)+1\cdot(-1,3,2,0)
=4\cdot(1/2,0/2,-1/2,2/2)+4\cdot(-1/4,3/4,2/4,0/4)$.

Answer (score 1):

For part 2, the first step is finding a basis where all coefficients are nonzero.

In the standard basis, the vector is
$$v=1e_1+3e_2+0e_3+4e_4 \tag{*}$$
which has a zero at $e_3$, which you want to get rid of. The trick to get that is to once add and once subtract it to another basis vector so that the term cancels out. Let's for example take $e_4$ as the “partner” vector, so your new basis is
$$f_1 = e_1, f_2 = e_2, f_3 = e_4-e_3, f_4 = e_4+e_3 \tag{**}$$
Reversing those equations gives
$$e_1 = f_1, e_2 = f_2, e_3 = \tfrac12(f_4-f_3),e_4 = \tfrac12(f_4+f_3)$$
which we can then insert in $\text{(*)}$ to find
$$v = 1f_1 + 3f_2 + 2f_3 + 2f_4 \tag{***}$$
Now we have four non-zero coefficients, but not the desired value $4$. But that can be resolved by simply rescaling the vectors:
$$g_1 = \tfrac14 f_1, g_2 = \tfrac34 f_2, g_3 = \frac12 f_3, g_4 = \frac12 f_4\tag{****}$$
Solving for $f_i$ and inserting in $\text{(***)}$ indeed shows that
$$v = 4g_1 + 4g_2 + 4g_3 + 4g_4$$
To get the actual form of the $g_k$, just insert $\text{(**)}$ in $\text{(****)}$. Doing so gives
$$\begin{aligned}
g_1 &= \tfrac14 e_1 = (\tfrac14,0,0,0)\\
g_2 &= \tfrac34 e_2 = (0,\tfrac34,0,0)\\
g_3 &= \tfrac12 (e_4-e_3) = (0,0,-\tfrac12,\tfrac12)\\
g_4 &= \tfrac12 (e_4+e_3) = (0,0,\tfrac12,\tfrac12)
\end{aligned}$$
Note that this is not the only basis that has this property.